# Share Point 2013 breadcrumb

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image]

I have enabled the ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox div to make the breadcrumb visible in share point 2013.

But as shown in the image above. the title 'This page Location is:' on the right. How can I fix this so that it is on the left.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above issue I included the following in my css file:

```
 .ms-breadcrumb-header{
margin-left:-50px;
 }
```